# Which Steam wishlist games are shared with me over family sharing?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

Is there a way to check the intersection between my wishlist and the games shared with me over family sharing?  In my case, both are very large.

If not through Steam, then maybe by visiting some website?  Or using a browser plugin?  Or an external program?

Comment: Is there a web-page version (not in the Steam client) of the games that you have from Family Sharing?

Comment: Im confused by what you are asking. Your wishlist can be seen by anyone that you have set to in your privacy settings. Your games that you have received through family share cannot be seen by anyone else other then the people using the account that was connected with it.

Comment: I think I understand the scenario - OP has access to a lot of games through family sharing, but they are still on their wish list. OP wants their wish list to be focused on games they don't have access to, and therefore wants a way to easily see which games overlap, and, possibly, remove them.

Comment: @ZAD-Man: Yes that, and also I'd like to play the ones I _do_ have access to.

Comment: Do you have access to both as a direct list? If you can bring them up so that you have a list of games, as direct text, it can be fairly simple to have the lists cross-compared. That said, I can only seem to get my wish list up as interactive buttons, so this method may not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the idea in Hagelt18's answer, I whipped together a quick tool to do all the hard work.

[image: Screenshot]

You can download the latest version [here](https://github.com/BlueRaja/SteamWishlistSharedLibrary/releases).
Requires [.Net 4.6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48130).
Please post any bugs [here](https://github.com/BlueRaja/SteamWishlistSharedLibrary/issues).

Comment: Just checked it out and it works great! I think it's awesome that we were able to build a solution where there wasn't one. That's the sign of a great community.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing in steam itself to do this and the Web API's do not have a way to retrieve a list of games in a wishlist. There are ways to get lists of games per user, but not wish list games.
 - [Steam Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) 
 - [Steamworks Web API](https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/webapi)

The only way for this to be possible would be to parse the html source behind the user's wishlist page. There is a user script out there created by Eisenzange which will return a list of games in a simple text format. I have modified it slightly so that it will return each game on a new line.

*Warning: These scripts are not guaranteed to work in the future as they make assumptions about the steam web page source. This is the only way to accomplish what you want at this time.*

**Retrieving the Wish List**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Steam Wishlist to Text
// @namespace   Eisenzange@steamgifts
// @include     /^https?://steamcommunity\.com/.+/wishlist.*$/
// @version     1.0.0
// ==/UserScript==
var wishlistElements = document.getElementsByTagName("h4"),
    wishlistNames = [],
    i;
for (i=0;i<wishlistElements.length;i++)
{
    wishlistNames.push(wishlistElements[i].innerHTML);
}
prompt("Wishlist:",wishlistNames.join("\r\n"));
```

If you aren't familiar with user scripts please check out this help page for an add-on called [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/faq.php).  After installing tampermonkey and enabling the script, you should be able to visit your wishlist by visiting the following URL with YourUserName replaced with your actual username:

http://steamcommunity.com/id/YourUserName/wishlist

Note: Your user page doesn't necessarily have to use your user name. If you don't know how to find a profile URL, [check out this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0a7gCHq-B0). It will show you in less than a minute.

When you visit the page a little prompt will come up (assuming your script is running) and it will give you a list of all the games. Copy and paste this into notepad or excel to see it all laid out.

**Retrieving the Game List**

Using http://steamcommunity.com/id/YourUserName/games/?tab=all  does not return all of your games.  Using [steamcommunity.com/id/YourUserName/games/?xml=1](http://steamcommunity.com/id/YourUserName/games/?xml=1) does return the list, but I could not get tampermonkey to read straight xml output. It was easier for me to write a quick program to do this. You could also use the Web API's mentioned above if you don't want to use my program. It runs on windows and only requires .NET Framework 4.0

[Stand Alone EXE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By7aWSCmf2bNZUNtMFpLLVRJbTA/view?usp=sharing)

[Source Code (zip)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By7aWSCmf2bNNFZ1Z1dDT0l1dzA/view?usp=sharing)

[Source Code (GitHub)](https://github.com/hagelt18/GetGameList)

**Comparing the two lists**

There are many tools out there you can use to compare lists. A simple google search gave me this tool which seems to work perfectly for what you need.  I was able to copy and paste the results from those scripts into the two list fields on this site and it worked perfectly.  Keep in mind that your original question wanted to see the games for multiple users and compare it to your wish list.  This tool still works if you paste both your games and the other user's games into the first list, then paste the wish list games into the second list.

http://jura.wi.mit.edu/bioc/tools/compare.php

**Results**
[image]

Comment: Your Steam game list does not display *all* the games you have access to (referring to games added via Family Sharing). Only those that you've have purchased (mobile site/app) or have recently played (regardless of owning it or not) for the desktop site.

Comment: Secondly, there isn't a way to retrieve a list of users who are sharing their games with you, and you could always try XML view for the game lists...

Comment: I realized that after I posted the answer and started looking at alternatives. The xml results do show all the games but I couldn't get the script to work for it. I just wrote a program to do it instead.

As for getting a list of users you have family share with, I didn't see anything even in the web api. I'm assuming you know who you are sharing with and it is no more than 5 users.

Comment: Could you upload the source for your program to github, instead of a zip file on google drive?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yep, I added a link in the answer.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft 
I noticed some of the game names were coming in with strange characters. This was due to an encoding issue. It has been corrected and all links updated.

Comment: Congrats on the well-deserved bounty, and welcome to the site! _(by the way, .Net has a built-in XML parser, there's no need to hack together your own :P)_

Comment: I've now created a tool to do this entire process automatically - see my answer for details.